# Java: create copy of ArrayList of HashMaps but include only certain keys

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream

Consider the following data structures:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> entries = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<String> keyNamesToInclude = new ArrayList<>();
```

This code creates a copy of *entries,* but with hashmaps only including the keys in keyNamesToInclude:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> copies = new ArrayList<>();

for (HashMap<String, String> entry: entries) {
  HashMap<String, String> copy = new HashMap<>();
  for (String keyName: keyNamesToInclude) {
    copy.put(keyName, entry.get(keyName));
  }
  copies.add(copy);
}
```

How would one create this with Streams in a functional way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to convert `keyNamesToInclude` into `Set` to facilitate lookup of the keys.

Then use `List::stream` to get `Stream<HashMap>` and for each map get filtered stream of its entries re-collected into a new map and list accordingly.

```java
Set<String> keys = new HashSet<>(keyNamesToInclude); // removes possible duplicates
List<Map<String, String>> copies = entries.stream() // Stream<HashMap>
    .map(m -> m.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(e -> keys.contains(e.getKey()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue
        ))
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If it is *very* important to have concrete implementations of `List` and `Map` in `copies`, casting or special forms of collectors may be needed even though `Collectors.toList()` returns `ArrayList` and `Collectors.toMap` returns `HashMap`:

```java
// casting
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> copies2 = (ArrayList) entries.stream() // Stream<HashMap>
    .map(m -> (HashMap<String, String>) m.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(e -> keys.contains(e.getKey()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue))
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

// special collectors
// toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper, mergeFunction, mapFactory)
// toList -> toCollection(ArrayList::new)
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> copies3 = entries.stream() // Stream<HashMap>
    .map(m -> m.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(e -> keys.contains(e.getKey()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> a, HashMap::new))
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like:

```java
Set<String> setNamesToInclude = new HashSet<>(keyNamesToInclude);
List<Map<String, String>> copies = entries.stream()
    .map(hm -> hm.keySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(setNamesToInclude::contains)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), hm::get))
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You are right. I shouldn't have used concrete `HashMap ` and `ArrayList ` types on the left-side of the assignment. However, I believe that `Function.identity()` should work as is, and the compiler should be able to deduce all the necessary types automatically.

Comment: I mean method reference `Function::identity` is not good :)

Comment:  Got it. Fixed. Thanks 

Answer (score 1):

Maybe somewhat more efficient solution that utilizes hashmap instead of list contains.

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> copies = maps.stream().map(e -> {
            HashMap<String, String> copy = new HashMap<>();
            keys.forEach(k -> {
                String value = e.get(k);
                if (value != null) 
                    copy.put(k, e.get(k));
            });
            return copy;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following (pseudo code):

```java
return entries.stream()
  .map(hashmap -> {
    return hashmap.stream()
      .filter((k,v) -> keyNamesToInclude.contains(k))
      .collect(toMap());
  })
  .collect(toList());
```

Comment: The inner lambda to map the `HashMap` can be replaced by an expression lambda.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a `Set` to contain the `keysToBeIncluded` since it is a little more efficient. This also filters out empty maps from the final list.

```
List<Map<String, String>> entries = List.of(
        Map.of("1", "one", "2", "two", "3", "three"),
        Map.of("2", "two", "3", "three"), Map.of("1", "one"),
        Map.of("6", "six", "7", "seven"));

entries.forEach(System.out::println);

Set<String> keyNamesToInclude = Set.of("2", "3", "6");
```

- stream the original list of maps
- for each map, filter the required keys
- build the new map
- filter to allow non-empty maps.
- create the list

```
List<Map<String, String>> copies = entries.stream()
        .map(m -> m.entrySet().stream().filter(
                e -> keyNamesToInclude.contains(e.getKey()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
                        Entry::getValue))).filter(m->!m.isEmpty())
        .toList();  // java 16 - can be replaced with a collector

copies.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints four lines of source and three lines of result

```
{3=three, 2=two, 1=one}
{3=three, 2=two}
{1=one}
{7=seven, 6=six}

{2=two, 3=three}
{2=two, 3=three}
{6=six}
```